# easy to create DSP app maker?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, desktop-application, labview

I am making an EEG bio-feedback'product' for a friend and I need a simple but DSP-powerful application builder.

Here is my situation:

I have built the HW to measure the brainwave signals and need to create a user panel for my friend to use it. The HW sends a stream of ascii out a serial port. The data packets send the amplitude value at a rate of 250 packets per second.  Brain waves of interest are below 30 HZ so this is more than fast enough sampling.

I am prototyping the DSP user panel in LabVIEW which makes it incredibly easy to do sophisticated DSP with a custom control panel. However, my friend just wants a plug and play product and I can hardly install LabVIEW on his PC, so here is my challenge: I am wondering if there is a design application that I can use to create the final application for him.

I have no problem if it is text based but I don't have the capacity to sit down with a full-on programming language to make the front panel controls, internal DSP and serial port processor, so the application would hopefully provide the designer easy to tool-up GUI and easy to access DSP library. I am up to coding stuff to interpret the serial data format and manage the general flow of the data to get it processed and sent to the front panel, but all the fussy details of setting up some programming IDE and installing a bunch of libraries to make the front panel is more than I can take on right now.

BTW, I also put this together in a private edition of Matlab but again that is no good for my friend.

Any ideas?  I know there are high-level application builders around but they usually target beginners.  I am so spoiled by Labview!  I have no problem with the actual coding like in C, Basic, or maybe Python, it's all the environment-building I don't want to get pulled into.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for answers to specific questions, and open-ended discussion questions don't fit the goals. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see more information about how to use Stack Overflow in a way most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a stand alone executable, you can use LabVIEW's application builder to create one. The app builder ships with LV pro, but can be purchased separately for cheaper versions. This won't let your friend modify the code, but I understand that's what you want.

There are also numerous ways to create plugin systems, if that's needed in your case. You can find various tutorials on that.

Be aware that some toolkits and modules require that you purchase distribution licenses as well. You would need to check whether you're using such a module.

Comment: NI SignalExpress might also be an option - the full version lets you run LabVIEW code (i.e. the I/O and DSP code you have developed) and would give your end user the ability to modify the display or acquisition without having to code themselves, and it's marginally cheaper than the LabVIEW application builder. http://www.ni.com/labview/signalexpress/